# rails 4 action mailer setting (SMTP) for webmail

Tags: email, smtp, webmail

i have a problem here, i can't find any smtp setting for webmail, after many hours i spend and its nothing,, i just and always find for gmail setting, like this

```
# ActionMailer settings
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  domain: 'gmail.com',
  user_name: '*****@gmail.com',
  password: '******',
  authentication: 'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true}
```

is there anyone knows how to configure it for webmail,,

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
domain: 'smtp.gmail.com',
```

Answer (score 0):

SMTP and IMAP settings you can find here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/userguide/using_IMAP_client.html

Example of ActionMailer configuration for webmail:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.mail.us-west-2.awsapps.com',
  port:                 465,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            'support@example.com' ,
  password:             'WEBMAIL_PASSWORD_HERE',
  authentication:       'plain',
  ssl: true
}

config.action_mailer.default_options = { from: 'support@example.com' }
```

`address` dependent on where your mailbox is located.